# Bootstrap 3 and jquery issues

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

There seems to be some problem with the version of bootstrap that comes with Visual studio 2013 or maybe there is something wrong with my implementation. I have used the materials available on [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com) and have this [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/310/)
As you can see I am able to get the button dropdown to work, but not the tooltip when in JSFiddle. However, when I run the same code in a visual studio MVC 5 project, the button dropdown also doesnt work. The button click doesnt pull down a menu and the tool tip doesnt show. Only the css shows, but the Javascript doesnt seem to be working. On my Chrome console I get this error.
[image]

Here is the page source of my simple MVC 5 page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>NewIndex</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    New Index page



    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <br />

    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>

    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

    <br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>



</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
Added the tooltip separately in [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8fXMA/)

I got this tooltip code from [the example here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Comment: Does the issue persist when you move the `script` tags to the very end of the `body` tag?

Comment: yes.. I tried that too. End positioning is only from a performance perspective right? Since this is a learning app I did not care for it too much.

Comment: It is also a performance boost but it can also prevent your code from working. If you don't wrap your code in a `$(document).ready(...` function, your code won't have loaded the DOM - and therefore won't be able to execute your code.

Comment: ok. But why do I need a document.ready? shouldn't this work out of the box ? there is no document.ready in the jsfiddle but it works there.. partially atleast..

Comment: where do I put the document.ready? I am not calling any jquery code anywhere

Comment: If you're not calling any extra code then you won't need to wrap anything else in a `ready` function. As for the JSFiddle, I'd assume that it loads in the scripts _after_ the dom is ready. Other then that, I could only guess it might be an issue with your `src` paths?

Comment: Im using a CDN to link to the CSS and JS for bootstrap. for jquery as well in a later attempt. Still the same problem

Comment: that did not change anything. It looks like Bootstrap is broken somehow. but that cant be right. Anything missing in my code. If you can check the Html and see.. all js and css files are loading. I can see them load in my Chrome Dev Tools

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle you provided I did not see any attempt at a tooltip, but I added one for you in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/314/). I added the `tooltip` in your `<a>` tag:

`data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!"`

Read more about tooltips for bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips).

**Edit**: Bootstrap documentation for [dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns) does not show any use of `sr-only`, removing that will fix your problem.

Comment: I got the problem for the button drop down. My code had 'sr-only' in the button class. What is that for? removed that and it worked for the button drop down. The bootstrap documentation is misleading!

Comment: now I need to figure out where the documentation is wrong or misleading for the tooltip!

Comment: @user20358 , I don't see anything in their documentation that says `sr-only`

Comment: I updated the question with the tooltip issue I was having. Im sorry I miscommunicated what I was meaning to say. I did not mean a tooltip on the dropdown. I meant it as a separate BootStrap component